# MDX linkmember equivalent in DAX

Tags: mdx, dax

Is there any equivalent of `linkmemeber` from MDX to DAX?

I am trying to migrate the following script from MDX to DAX

```
   with 

member TauxdetransformationQuartileRegion  as ([Measures].[Taux_de_transformation_Region],[Bon Envoi].[Bon Envoi].&[True])
member Annees as [Date Creation].[Année].currentmember.name
select  {    

        [Measures].[Tx_Real_Meilleur_Region]
        ,TauxdetransformationQuartileRegion

      } on 0

FROM ( select strtoset(@Region) on 0 from test) 


 WHERE (
 linkmember(strtotuple(@DateFin),[Mois Publication].[Mois de publication]) 
 ,{strtotuple(@DateDebut):strtotuple(@DateFin)} 
 ,[Perimetre Ebusiness].[Périmètre E-Business].&[O]
 ,{[MER_Publication].[Detail Type Visiteur].&[Prospect],[MER_Publication].[Detail Type Visiteur].&[Client direct]}
 ,( - { [Origine_Marketing].[Entree Parcours].&[SiteAgent] } )

)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do with sample data?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDX query parameters are typically strings with member unique names (`"[Dim].[Attr].&[Key]"`) which you must convert to a member with `StrToMember(@Param)`. And if you need to switch hierarchies you the use `LinkMember`.

DAX parameters are just the values. So the parameter will work against any dimension. Thus LinkMember isn’t needed.

Here is an article about [DAX parameters](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2012/01/05/use-parameters-in-your-dax-queries/). For Date type parameters I forget if you just say `'Date'[Date] = @DateParam` or if you have to say `'Date'[Date] = DATEVALUE(@DateParam)`. My recollection is that it depends on whether the parameter is Date type (use the first approach) or String type (use the DATEVALUE approach).

Comment: Do you know what it is the equivalent of the two commands strtoset and strtotuple from MDX to dax?

Comment: @csharp what version of SSAS? What client tool? SSRS?